# Replace a certain part of a text in a line - python

Tags: python, file, replace, ansys

I have a .wbjn file (ANSYS workbench journal file) which is a python file in which I have to replace certain variables. Eg.

```
parameter_1 = variable_1
parameter_2 = variable_2
.
.
parameter_n = variable_n
```

I have to replace the variables_1....n with a list of values.

So I created a mapping dictionary and iterated over it to replace the values. But the values are not getting replaced with the code I wrote;

```
map_dict = {'variable_1':'20','variable_2':'15'}
handle = open("filename.wbjn","r+")
for l in handle:
    for k,v in map_dict.items():
        l = l.replace(k,str(v))
    handle.write(l)
handle.close()
```

The file has several other lines which do not need to be modified. What is the problem here and how do I solve it.

Thanks

Comment: What output do you want.

Comment: parameter_1 = 20
parameter_2 = 30
....... and so on

Comment: You can't write to the file you are reading. That implies random access, for which textfiles are ill-suited. Write your converted stuff to a fresh, empty file. Then rename the files afterwards. Look at the module `in-place` if this is troublesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, already after reading the first line, it jumps at the end of the fileto write, and after that there is no other line. Mine is not the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
map_dict = {"variable_1": "20", "variable_2": "15"}
handle = open("filename.wbjn", "r+")
processed = []
for l in handle:
    for k, v in map_dict.items():
        l = l.replace(k, str(v))
    processed.append(l)
handle.seek(0)
handle.write("".join(processed))
handle.truncate()
handle.close()
```

Comment: This solved my problem thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `fileinput` package which enables to edit files `in-place`. Please find the draft that you can experiment with:

Example file.txt:

```
parameter_1 = variable_1
parameter_n = variable_n
parameter_4 = variable_4
parameter_k = variable_k
```

Script

```
from fileinput import FileInput

map_dict = {'variable_1': '20', 'variable_4': '15'}

with FileInput('file.txt', inplace=True) as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        parts = line.split('=')
        parameter = parts[0].strip()
        variable = parts[1].strip()
        if variable in map_dict:
            print(f"{parameter} = {map_dict[variable]}")
        else:
            print(line)
```

file.txt after execution

```
parameter_1 = 20
parameter_k = variable_n
parameter_4 = 15
parameter_k = variable_k
```

Please note that `print` function does not show in the script output but writes lines into the file.

For details please find [fileinput documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html)

Comment: This logic will not work in my case because as I mentioned earlier, there are several other lines which need not be modified. Since these lines cannot be split based on the "=" identifier, they would case errors

Comment: As I mentioned its just a draft how to edit file in place effectively. You need to handle those cases if there are different types of lines. I have provided solution which solves your provided example. You could give some examples where no `=` char is included to create the solution more general.